# Return this in Object to create chain

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, chaining

I'm trying to write a small XHR abstraction as well as learn how to create chainable methods, I am nearly there (I think), but am at a loss as to what to do next, I think my setup is wrong.

What I want to do:

```
$http.get('file.txt')
.success(function () {
    console.log('Success');
})
.error(function () {
    console.log('Error');
});
```

What I've got:

```
window.$http = {};

$http.get = function (url, cb, data) {

    var xhr = {
        success: function (callback) {
            callback();
            return this;
        },
        error: function (callback) {
            callback();
            return this;
        }
    };

    // just a test to call the success message
    if (window) {
        xhr.success.call(xhr);
    }

    return xhr;
};
```

I'm having trouble 'wiring' up the success/error messages, can anybody help point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZq83/)

Answer (score 1):

Your chaining is OK, but you have a error at this line:

```
 if (window) {
     xhr.success.call(xhr); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
  }
```

So JavaScript breaks and doesn't return xhr. Delete thoses lines and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Cerbrus for the typo correction. I wrote a little fast and English is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

`success` and `error` are simply functions that store the passed functions into an internal storage. Once the XHR responds, your code should execute all callbacks accordingly, depending on the response status.

Now what you need is an object instance per request that stores its own set of success and error callbacks. Also, `success` and `error` methods should return the same instance to allow chaining.

This should set you to the right track:

```
(function (window) {

    window.$http = {};

    // An object constructor for your XHR object
    function XHRObject(url,data){

        // store the request data
        this.url = url;
        this.data = data;

        // The callback storage
        this.callbacks = {};

        this.init();
    }

    // Methods
    XHRObject.prototype = {
        init : function(){
          // Actual call here

          // Depending on result, execute callbacks
          var callbacksToExecute;
          if(readyState === 4 && response.status === 200){
            callbacksToExecute = this.callbacks.success;
          } else {
            callbacksToExecute = this.callbacks.error;
          }
          callbacksToExecute.forEach(function(callback){
            callback.call(null);
          });
        },
        success : function(cb){

            // Create a success callback array and store the callback
            if(this.callbacks.hasOwnProperty('success') this.callbacks.success = [];
            this.callbacks.success.push(cb);

            // You also need a flag to tell future callbacks to execute immediately
            // if the current object has already responded

            return this;
        },
        ...
    }

    // A call to get basically returns an object
    $http.get = function (url, data) {
         return new XHRObject(url,data);
    };

})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can make something out of this:

```
window.$http = {};
$http.get = function (url, cb, data) {
    var xhr = function(){
        return {
            success: function (callback) {
                callback();
                return this;
            },
            error: function (callback) {
                callback();
                return this;
            }
        };
    };
    return new xhr();
}

$http.get('url','cb','data')
.success(function () {
    console.log('Success');
})
.error(function () {
    console.log('Error');
});
```

Edit: I just realized this is basically the same code you wrote, except I'm missing the `if()`. It seems that test was causing the code to break.